# Ireports and barcode

Tags: java, ireport, barcode

I am doing a report that contains barcodes, but when I compile it, it gives me a error

```
    Compilation exceptions: com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.ErrorsCollector@eed1de
  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: 
  1. it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage cannot be resolved to a type                 
  value = (java.awt.Image)(it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage.getBarcodeImage(26,"*"+((java.lang.String)field_NRIDENTSNS.getValue())+"*",false,false,null,0,0)); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$                                          
  <--------------------------------------> 
  2. it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage cannot be resolved to a type                 
  value = (java.awt.Image)(it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage.getBarcodeImage(26,"*"+((java.lang.String)field_NRIDENTSNS.getValue())+"*",false,false,null,0,0)); //$JR_EXPR_ID=13$                                          
  <--------------------------------------> 
  3. it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage cannot be resolved to a type                 
  value = (java.awt.Image)(it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage.getBarcodeImage(26,"*"+((java.lang.String)field_NRIDENTSNS.getOldValue())+"*",false,false,null,0,0)); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$                                          
  <--------------------------------------> 
  4. it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage cannot be resolved to a type                 
  value = (java.awt.Image)(it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage.getBarcodeImage(26,"*"+((java.lang.String)field_NRIDENTSNS.getOldValue())+"*",false,false,null,0,0)); //$JR_EXPR_ID=13$                                          
  <--------------------------------------> 
  5. it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage cannot be resolved to a type                 
  value = (java.awt.Image)(it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage.getBarcodeImage(26,"*"+((java.lang.String)field_NRIDENTSNS.getValue())+"*",false,false,null,0,0)); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$                                          
  <--------------------------------------> 
  6. it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage cannot be resolved to a type                 
  value = (java.awt.Image)(it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage.getBarcodeImage(26,"*"+((java.lang.String)field_NRIDENTSNS.getValue())+"*",false,false,null,0,0)); //$JR_EXPR_ID=13$                                          
  <--------------------------------------> 
  6 errors      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:191)     at com.jaspersoft.ireport.desig![enter image description here][1]ner.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:494)     at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)     at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997) 
Compilation running time: 4.807
```

What i am doing wrong? i am using ireports 3.7.0

this is my classpath:

http://img857.imageshack.us/img857/6145/classpath.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if there is a file `barbecue-1.1.jar` (it contains `BcImage.class`) in the `/web-inf/lib` folder. If not, add it.

Comment: but i am preview it when gives me that error. where is that folder?

Comment: just download that file, add it in the classpath but continues to give me the same error

Comment: check if .jar file contains that `BcImage.class`, if not this class is inside `iReport-utils-2.0.1.jar`, so put it also in `/web-inf/lib`